# HTML Error Log for Css

Tags: c#, css

I have the fallowing code that i used to use to log errors with visual basic is there any way i can create an error log such as this for C# ?

```
Private Sub writelog(ByVal title As String, ByVal data As String, ByVal isError As Boolean, ByVal logname As String)
    If write_log = True Then
        Try
            Dim data_con As String
            data_con = "<table border=""1"" bordercolor=""#0099FF"" style=""background-color:#FFFFFF"" width=""100%"" cellpadding=""2"" cellspacing=""2"">" & vbCrLf & _
                           "<tr>" & vbCrLf
            If isError = True Then
                data_con = data_con & "<td WIDTH=""15%"" bgcolor=""#FFFF99"" bordercolor=""RED""><b><FONT COLOR=""RED"">" & title & "</font></b></td>" & vbCrLf
                data_con = data_con & "<td WIDTH=""70%"" bgcolor=""#FFFF99"" bordercolor=""RED"">" & data & "</td>" & vbCrLf & _
                              "<td WIDTH=""15%"" bgcolor=""#FFFF99"" bordercolor=""RED"">" & DateAndTime.Now & "</td>" & vbCrLf & _
                          "</tr></table>"
            Else
                data_con = data_con & "<td WIDTH=""15%""><b><FONT COLOR=""GREEN"">" & title & "</font></b></td>" & vbCrLf
                data_con = data_con & "<td WIDTH=""70%"">" & data & "</td>" & vbCrLf & _
                              "<td WIDTH=""15%"">" & DateAndTime.Now & "</td>" & vbCrLf & _
                          "</tr></table>"
            End If

            My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\" & logname & ".html", data_con & vbCrLf, True)
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You can just convert this code into C#, I don't see where the css comes into it though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     private void writelog(string title, string data, bool isError, string logname) {
            if ((write_log == true)) {
                try {
                    string data_con;
                    data_con = ("<table border=\"1\" bordercolor=\"#0099FF\" style=\"background-color:#FFFFFF\" width=\"100%\" cellpadding=\"2\"" +
                    " cellspacing=\"2\">" + ("\r\n" + ("<tr>" + "\r\n")));
                    if ((isError == true)) {
                        data_con = (data_con + ("<td WIDTH=\"15%\" bgcolor=\"#FFFF99\" bordercolor=\"RED\"><b><FONT COLOR=\"RED\">" 
                                    + (title + ("</font></b></td>" + "\r\n"))));
                        data_con = (data_con + ("<td WIDTH=\"70%\" bgcolor=\"#FFFF99\" bordercolor=\"RED\">" 
                                    + (data + ("</td>" + ("\r\n" + ("<td WIDTH=\"15%\" bgcolor=\"#FFFF99\" bordercolor=\"RED\">" 
                                    + (DateAndTime.Now + ("</td>" + ("\r\n" + "</tr></table>")))))))));
                    }
                    else {
                        data_con = (data_con + ("<td WIDTH=\"15%\"><b><FONT COLOR=\"GREEN\">" 
                                    + (title + ("</font></b></td>" + "\r\n"))));
                        data_con = (data_con + ("<td WIDTH=\"70%\">" 
                                    + (data + ("</td>" + ("\r\n" + ("<td WIDTH=\"15%\">" 
                                    + (DateAndTime.Now + ("</td>" + ("\r\n" + "</tr></table>")))))))));
                        }
                     File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine("Put here your log directory path",logname), data_con);

                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: ok thanks! now how would I dim Write_log as Boolean in C#

Comment: I can't get it to create the file... any ideas this is the sanple string i am using to generate a msg to the file
   writelog("Application Warning", "This is an Example of a Warning", False, "App_System")

Comment: i fixed this issue by the way Thank YOU !